# Install wand package in Conda on Windows

Tags: python, windows, imagemagick, conda, wand

I am looking for help installing wand as a Conda newbie. I was successful installing and using wand outside of Conda on this machine. I am running ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16-HDRI system-wide. When I run:

```
conda install -c conda-forge wand
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 wand
```

as recommended at [conda forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/wand), this is the result:

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 wand
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==10.2=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 10.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the conda error message is misleading. The wand package at conda-forge is in error. Instead I installed wand through pip:

```
conda install pip
pip install Wand
```